# In java, how would I determine if a square is the size of a single pixel?

Tags: java, recursion

I am having to draw recursively a sierpinski triangle by drawing three one-pixel squares on top of each other to make a triangle. He tells us, and im assuming this will be my recursive base case, that "The draw algorithm will take the coordinates of a square area of the screen as input. If that square is the size of a single pizel, it should call drawRect() on the object passed into paintComponent, drawing a one-pixel square somehwhere on the screen."

How do i find out if the square area of the screen is the size of a single pixel? Do i just send in the width of the area when i call the method and do width^2. If the area is 1, does that mean its 1 pixel?

Comment: yes, the dimensions in java are usually in pixels

Comment: to be a bit trite, the same way you would determine the size of a square that is 100 pixels.

Comment: The base case in this sense means that here is no point recursing because the smallest size (three 1x1 pixel "boxes" in a triangle) is already drawn. So, wherever the recursion *starts* from, it should be "significantly large" than 1 pixel triangles. That is, start with *triangles* - not boxes, as that'd be not triangles - that have a base of 400 pixels or so.

Answer (score 0):

The square (or probably the `Rectangle`) has size of one Pixel if:

```
java.awt.Rectangle rect;
// ....
boolean isOnePixel = (rect.width == 1 && rect.height == 1);
```

To simplify things we asume the witdh and height cannot be negative.
Altough Java rectangle classes permits that.